# Load data for Last month when Insert date > 10th day of the month

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, where-clause

I have a fact Table For eg Table X. I need to write a query to load last month data only when the insert date is greater than 10th of the month.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the 10th day of the current month with an expression like:

```
datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 10)
```

If you want to compute this from a table column, you can just replace `getdate()` with the relevant column name.

It is rather unclear how you want to use this computation in your query though. If you want to filter the table for `insert_date`s greater than the 10th of the current month, you would do:

```
select * from tablex where insert_date >= datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 10);
```

If you want to filter on the 10th of each month, then:

```
select * from tablex where day(insert_date) >= 10
```